# How to deal with a manager snooping on employees through security cameras and other technical means

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, india

I had a conversation with a colleague over IPMessenger in the office. A few days later the manager made remarks that clearly sounded like what I had said in that conversation. Specifically, I had made a remark that although the company is an MNC but was being run like a Baniye ki dukaan aka a 7-11. In the meeting, the manager asked if everyone was happy with the way things are since he feels some employees are disgruntled and feel like the office is being run like a baniye ki dukaan aka 7-11, De Ja Vu...He uses the security cameras to listen in to employee conversation and all. One day I was heading home around 08:30 PM(late). He saw me leaving on the camera and accosted me on the way out, started using expletives and abused me verbally for trying to leave while managers were still in the office. Specifically, he showed me his wristwatch before showering me with abuses...How do I deal with such a manager?

**EDIT:**
I can't loose this job for the following reasons:

1. Don't want to leave home town (Indore, India). Moving to another city would entail cost of living eating into any hike I get over the current salary.
2. Mother is undergoing treatment for cancer so cannot leave city anyways.
3. No other company in the city can match the salary, this company is an offshore captive development center for a US Fortune 200 Company. Biggest name in the Environmental Services (Garbage Collection, Landfills, Power Plants et al)
4. On my way up the ladder to become a Manager. Finally why should I after 8 years

Comment: What is your goal? What would you like to accomplish by dealing with him? I know those may seem like obvious questions, but knowing the answers can help people give you more specific answers. If you really want to stay employed by this company, versus being willing to just cut your losses and get a job elsewhere, the answers may be different.

Comment: Updating the location to India. The term `Baniye ki dukaan` is basically a euphenism for the way many family owned small businesses run in India by overworking their workers.

Comment: Are you contractually bound to stay with this employer? If you're in India, will there be problems getting a relieving letter or anything else you need in order to separate from this employer?

Comment: I can't loose this job for the following reasons:
1. Don't want to leave home town(Indore, India). Moving to another city would entail cost of living eating into any hike I get over the current salary. 
2. Mother is undergoing treatment for cancer so cannot leave city anyways.
3. No other company in the city can match the salary, this company is an offshore captive development center for a US Fortune 200 Company. Biggest name in the Environmental Services (Garbage Collection, Landfills, Power Plants et al) 
4. On my way up the ladder to become a Manager. Finally why should I after 8 years.

Comment: Thanks @mu無 for clarifying for everyone...

Comment: Wow...5 downvotes...maybe the manager's approach is right...I am being an ass for taking offense....

Comment: Is it time to employ Office Space office exit strategy? I.e. leave the office without people seeing you.

Comment: Actually I decided to stay and fight...It was 10:30 PM yesterday in office, and the manager was in the cubicles discussing with others...Showed him my wristwatch...Pointing at it with the other hand...Made hand gestures to the effect What the heck...Almost midnight...

Answer (score 1):

Two important considerations: Where are you, and what is the position of your manager? Here in the UK the manager's behaviour would be unacceptable. The company would in danger of getting into trouble through his or her behaviour, so the company would most likely act if they found out. It would be both legal trouble, and trouble through unhappy employees.

If this behaviour is more acceptable where you live, you should still find out if it is acceptable in your company. Your manager's boss might find the manager's behaviour unacceptable and might be willing to do something about it - if they knew. That's up to you to find out.

Comment: I am in Indore, India. My manager is also the director. He looks after India operations of the company. Other colleagues are from socio-economically weaker families and thus tolerate his crap. But, I am from a much better off section. The manager took the .Net team to a hotel for a party on my(The Champ's) birthday. I heard him say to a visiting colleague from US office that apart from SiD, none of these guys can afford this place. When I asked him when will the team expand. He said, slipping his shoe by the side of the table, those are hush puppies and you are gonna get one right up yours.

Answer (score 0):

My question to you is: Knowing how bad the things are, why are you still working at a place like that ? Are you that desperate ? And if yes, why ? You need to address your deficiencies and address them and get the hell out of that place as fast as your shoes can carry you. No job is worth the abuse.

Comment: @SiD That is a very bad idea. Insulting the manager's family, in writing, where it's publicly viewable?  What would that accomplish?  The manager may feel insulted temporarily, but ultimately this approach would do more damage to yourself.